# How to leave simulator open after test run?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, automated-tests, ios-simulator

When running a UI Test, how do I keep the simulator open so I can manually test additional steps?

After a UI Test completes, the simulator will shut down. I'd like to use the UI Test as an automation to reach a certain point in the app. Then I'll do a few additional things not covered by the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an option for that. You should separate your automatic and manual testing. Automatic testing ideally should be done on a CI. You should do your manual testing separately from UI tests.